# Customer application icon is not showing in taskbar - why?

Tags: c#, wpf, icons

**Situation:** Implementing a WPF application with VS 2012 and added a custom icon to the main window with tag `Icon="images\myIcon.gif">`.

When starting the WPF application out of VS 2012 with `CTRL + F5` the icon will be shown in the taskbar and in the left top corner of the main window.

**Problem:** I published my application with VS 2012's publishing wizard (One Click installing routine) and installed the application on my computer. When starting the installed application the left top icon ist still shown in the main window, but the taskbar icon not. Instead a windows default icon is shown.

**Question:** Does someone know what the problem is or what I have been missing?

Comment: Try using the following path: `Icon="/ApplicationName;component/images/myIcon.gif">` instead.

Comment: This is a ClickOnce settings problem. So it would be nice to tag it as click-once and to add a ClickOnce mention to the title. Otherwise it can be misleading for people who search for a solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.icon):

> Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) standalone applications have two
> types of icons:
>
> - One assembly icon, which is specified by using the  property
>   in the application's project build file. This icon is used as the desktop
>   icon for an assembly.
> - One icon per window that is specified by setting Icon. For each window,
>   this icon is used in its title bar, its task bar button, and
>   in its ALT-TAB application selection list entry.

If you want to display an icon in the taskbar, you need to set the assembly/application icon:

- Open the properties of your project deployed by ClickOnce
- *Application* --> *Resources*
- Select *Icon and manifest* and browse for the icon you desire

Comment: Still not showing: I change the MainWindow during startup (splash screen). Any ideas?

Answer (score -2):

ShowInTaskbar="True"

Comment: This is the default value. So unless op explicitly set it to False, that won't help.

Comment: In my case this was the solution for my problem, because a previous developer set this flag to false. (This answer matches to the title. The Click Once related side node was slightly hidden inside of the description text.)